# Is pdflatex javascript this.getTemplate("Template-Name") possible

Tags: javascript, acrotex

I would like to display a pdf page base on a selection box. If selection 1 is used, display page 1, if selection 2 is used display page 2.
It is a kind of product datasheet and only the data of the selected product should be visible. 
I got some infos from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460835/how-to-show-hide-a-page-of-a-pdf-form-by-checking-or-unchecking-a-check-box) but this solve not my question in latex.

Comment: javascript is not supported by most pdf readers, if that is a concern.

Comment: @Hans Consider PDF layers (OCGs) as a JS-free option, using e. g.  pkg `ocgx2`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508645