# Is it possible to have different layers on/off switchable?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a complex tikz graph with different layers of information.
I.E. one layer with red edges, another one with blue edges, etc.

Is there a way to create a document with checkboxes that enable the different layers independently?
That should work under windows and linux if possible

What would be the way to go?

Comment: Welcome! I never used it, but maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508630/stacking-pdf-layers can help?

Comment: Also https://texdoc.org/serve/ocgx2/0 --- the author is quite active here, so maybe you can post a simple [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and see what happens...

Comment: See the eforms package for check boxes, radio buttons, list boxes and trigger events.