# Stacking pdf layers: MWE breaks linux pdf viewers okular and evince

Tags: ocgx2

I would have commented on [Stacking pdf layers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508630/stacking-pdf-layers)
But lacking the reputation, I'll have to open a new thread.

However

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[samin, norsk, nynorsk, british]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % usually not needed (loaded by default)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}

\newcommand{\UNItitlebox}[2]{% #1: logo, #2: language
  \frame{%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\centering
      \vspace{1pt}
      \hrule height 1pt
      \vspace{1.2em}
      \includegraphics[height=1.69cm,width=12.8cm]{#1}\\[5pt]
      \makebox[12.8cm]{MAT-1001\quad Calculus\hfill #2}\\[5pt]
      \makebox[12.8cm]{Exam\hfill 23/09/2019}\\[5pt]
      \vspace{1em}
      \hrule height 1pt
      \vspace{1pt}
    \end{minipage}%
  }
}

% Hyperlenker og klikkbare lenker.
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

{%
  \noindent\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 0}% locally suppress link borders
  \begin{ocmd}{\AllOff{ocg1}}\makebox[0pt][l]{English}\end{ocmd}% black, "on" if ocg1 is "off"
  \showocg{ocg1}{%
    \begin{ocmd}{\AllOn{ocg1}} % green if ocg1 "on"
      \color{green!50!black}English
    \end{ocmd}}\hfill
  %  
  \begin{ocmd}{\AllOff{ocg2}}\makebox[0pt][l]{Bokmål}\end{ocmd}% black, "on" if ocg2 is "off"
  \showocg{ocg2}{%
    \begin{ocmd}{\AllOn{ocg2}} % green if ocg2 "on"
      \color{green!50!black}Bokmål
    \end{ocmd}}\hfill
  %  
  \begin{ocmd}{\AllOff{ocg3}}\makebox[0pt][l]{Nynorsk}\end{ocmd}% black, "on" if ocg3 is "off"
  \showocg{ocg3}{%
    \begin{ocmd}{\AllOn{ocg3}} % green if ocg3 "on"
      \color{green!50!black}Nynorsk
    \end{ocmd}}\hfill
  %  
  \begin{ocmd}{\AllOff{ocg4}}\makebox[0pt][l]{Samisk}\end{ocmd}% black, "on" if ocg4 is "off"
  \showocg{ocg4}{%
    \begin{ocmd}{\AllOn{ocg4}} % green if ocg4 "on"
      \color{green!50!black}Samisk
    \end{ocmd}}%
}  

\bigskip

\begin{center}
%
\begin{ocg}[radiobtngrp=languages]{OCG 1}{ocg1}{on}
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\UNItitlebox{example-image-a}{English}}
\end{ocg}%
%
\begin{ocg}[radiobtngrp=languages]{OCG 2}{ocg2}{off}
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\UNItitlebox{example-image-b}{Bokmål}}
\end{ocg}%
%
\begin{ocg}[radiobtngrp=languages]{OCG 3}{ocg3}{off}
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\UNItitlebox{example-image-c}{Nynorsk}}
\end{ocg}%
\begin{ocg}[radiobtngrp=languages]{OCG 4}{ocg4}{off}
  \UNItitlebox{example-image}{Samisk}
\end{ocg}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

That is the provided MWE in said thread.
`pdflatex` executed twice creates a pdf that - on click on any of the links - crashes okular and evince. Can someone reproduce that? Or is that a local thing?

Edit: evince tells something

```
(evince:153726): Poppler-CRITICAL **: 21:40:03.966: gint poppler_layer_get_radio_button_group_id(PopplerLayer*): assertion 'POPPLER_IS_LAYER(poppler_layer)' failed

(evince:153726): Poppler-CRITICAL **: 21:40:03.966: gboolean poppler_layer_is_parent(PopplerLayer*): assertion 'POPPLER_IS_LAYER(poppler_layer)' failed

(evince:153726): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 21:40:03.966: g_object_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(evince:153726): Poppler-CRITICAL **: 21:40:03.966: gint poppler_layer_get_radio_button_group_id(PopplerLayer*): assertion 'POPPLER_IS_LAYER(poppler_layer)' failed

(evince:153726): Poppler-CRITICAL **: 21:40:03.966: gboolean poppler_layer_is_parent(PopplerLayer*): assertion 'POPPLER_IS_LAYER(poppler_layer)' failed

(evince:153726): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 21:40:03.966: g_object_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(evince:153726): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 21:40:03.966: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(evince:153726): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 21:40:03.966: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(evince:153726): Poppler-CRITICAL **: 21:40:05.680: void poppler_layer_show(PopplerLayer*): assertion 'POPPLER_IS_LAYER(poppler_layer)' failed

(evince:153726): Poppler-CRITICAL **: 21:40:11.487: void poppler_layer_show(PopplerLayer*): assertion 'POPPLER_IS_LAYER(poppler_layer)' failed
```

Comment: Works for me in both Okular, v20.12.3, and Evince aka Document Viewer, v3.36.10. Poppler lib is v21.02.0.

Comment: Same here with Okular 1.9.3, evince  3.36.7, and also Acrobat X 10.0.0 on Windows (so quite older versions than @AlexG): works ok. `xpdf` does not react to the click but it doesn't crash either.

Comment: okular 20.12.3
poppler 21.04.0-2, just tested again - rly broken.

Comment: Which is your Linux distro? I installed poppler 21.04.0 and re-checked. It works too. It seems there is something wrong with your OS.

Comment: arch 10 8 6 4 0

Comment: Could you try building poppler and evince from the sources? Does Arch offer this option?

Comment: @user239572 It seems an Arch issue. I asked in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57651698#57651698) and the error could be reproduced.